# How do I change the group of a custom product attribute?

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute

I've created several custom product attributes like this:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', $data['name'], array(
    'group'             => 'General',
    'type'              => $data['type'],
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => $data['front_end'],
    'label'             => $data['label'],
    'input'             => $data['input'],
    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    ));
```

Because I'm creating several attributes, the above code runs in a loop (hence the data variable).  I've copied the relevant portion (I think); there's several more fields being set, but I've excluded them for brevity.

I'd like to change their group to a custom one I've created in an upgrade script.  I'm able to set this correctly if I remove the module and recreate it.  However, I would like to be able to change the group through an upgrade script since the code has already been deployed.

I've tried this with no luck:

```
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', $data['name'], array(
    'group' => 'Custom Product Tab'
));
```

How can I modify a product attribute's group in an upgrade script?

Comment: $installer above is a reference to $this, which is defined as `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`

Comment: If attribute will created then you can also assign that custom attribute using admin panel of magento It's so simple

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041362/update-customer-address-attribute-in-magento-via-upgrade-script

Comment: @KeyulShah, using the admin interface is not practical when distributing code.

Comment: hmmmm ok nor prb

Answer (score 6):

See my code, it works perfectly:

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute = $installer->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'some_attribute');
$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, //catalog_product
    $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY), //Attribute Set Id
    'General', //Group Name
    $attribute['attribute_id'], //attribute id
    10//sort order
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: I'm unable to get this to change the group from General to a new group.  Is this part of an installation script, or an upgrade script?

Comment: @Toast It is upgrade, you should change group name in the code. If you put your install scrpit in your questin it will be easy to orientate for me

Comment: My install script and my upgrade script are in the question (the relevant parts).  As far as I can tell, your code doesn't work.

Comment: @Toast are you sure upgrede script runs. And which attribute set your attributes were added to, "Default"? I tested with standard magento attribute "cost", try first this attribute to add the group "General".

Comment: I'm positive the script runs.  I don't believe I'm setting an attribute set anywhere (you can see the install script in my answer).  I'm able to recreate the attributes in a different group, but I cannot change them after installation.

Comment: Have you tried exactly my code like with "cost" attribute, it should move it to General tab.

Comment: This will be my last comment since our thread is getting quite long.  No, I have not tried moving an existing product attribute because that does not solve my problem.